# How to create an index of pair unique for Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go

I am working with MongoDB, I want to make a pair unique on 2 field.

The below is what I have done so far :

```
func (repository *TranslationRepository) createIndexes(collection *mongo.Collection) error {
    models := []mongo.IndexModel{
        {
            Keys:    bson.D{{"object_id", 1}, {"object_type", 1}},
            Options: options.Index().SetUnique(true),
        },
        {
            Keys:    bson.D{{"expire_at", 1}},
            Options: options.Index().SetExpireAfterSeconds(0),
        },
    }

    opts := options.CreateIndexes().SetMaxTime(10 * time.Second)
    _, err := collection.Indexes().CreateMany(context.Background(), models, opts)
    return err
}
```

However when I insert 2 records like this

```
{
    "object_id"  : "abc",
    "object_type": "SAMPLE" 
}

{
    "object_id"  : "edf",
    "object_type": "SAMPLE" 
}
```

In the database, there will be only 1 record of

```
{
    "object_id"  : "edf",
    "object_type": "SAMPLE" 
}
```

The second already overwrited the first

The below is my sample code of inserting a record

```
TranslationForm := entity.TranslationForm{
        ObjectID:       "ABC",
        ObjectType:     "SAMPLE",
        SourceLanguage: "en",
        TargetLanguage: "cn",
        Content:        "something",
        ExpireAt:       time.Now(),
    }
res, err := repository.collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), TranslationForm)
```

Comment: Your index setup is correct. It is likely that you have another error.

Comment: Show how you insert those records, and how you check

Comment: No, show how you actually inserted those two records, and how you verified that there is only one. also, check the errors from the first insertion.

Comment: I made an index so I expect it will override if it is duplicate. and for those 2 inputs, I got no error.

Comment: The insert would return an error if the index prevented the duplicate entry, it would not just overwrite.  How did you do the inserts?

Comment: Your setup works for me. Please show us how you insert those 2 records. Also note that the example you showed uses `time.Now()` as the expiration, which means the inserted records may be purged at any time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have managed your scenario. Let me share a simple program to show off what I achieved.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type Object struct {
    ObjectId   string `json:"object_id" bson:"object_id"`
    ObjectType string `json:"object_type" bson:"object_type"`
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*10)
    defer cancelFunc()

    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017")
    mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer mongoClient.Disconnect(ctx)

    demoDb := mongoClient.Database("demodb")
    defer demoDb.Drop(ctx)
    myCollection := demoDb.Collection("myCollection")
    defer myCollection.Drop(ctx)

    // create index
    indexModel := mongo.IndexModel{
        Keys: bson.D{
            bson.E{
                Key:   "object_id",
                Value: 1,
            },
            bson.E{
                Key:   "object_type",
                Value: 1,
            },
        },
        Options: options.Index().SetUnique(true),
    }
    idxName, err := myCollection.Indexes().CreateOne(ctx, indexModel)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("index name:", idxName)

    // delete documents
    defer func() {
        if _, err := myCollection.DeleteMany(ctx, bson.M{}); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    // insert first doc
    res, err := myCollection.InsertOne(ctx, Object{ObjectId: "abc", ObjectType: "SAMPLE"})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res.InsertedID)

    // insert second doc
    // res, err = myCollection.InsertOne(ctx, Object{ObjectId: "abc", ObjectType: "SAMPLE"}) => ERROR
    res, err = myCollection.InsertOne(ctx, Object{ObjectId: "def", ObjectType: "SAMPLE"}) // => OK!
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res.InsertedID)

    // list all docs
    var objects []Object
    cursor, err := myCollection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err = cursor.All(ctx, &objects); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(objects)
}
```

Now, I'm gonna recap all of the main steps:

1. Definition of the `Object` struct which is a simplified version of what you need. Please note the `bson` annotations that are the ones actually used. For the sake of this demo, you can safely omit the `json` ones.
2. The setup related to the Mongo ecosystem:

   1. Context creation (with a timeout)
   2. Client set up (connection to a local MongoDB instance run via Docker)
   3. Creation of a database called `demodb` and a collection called `myCollection`. Plus, I deferred the calls to delete this stuff while exiting the programs (just for clean-up).
3. Creation of a unique compound index on the fields `object_id` and `object_type`. Pay attention to the `Options` field that states the uniqueness of the index with the method `SetUnique`.
4. Adding documents. Please note that the program won't allow you to insert two documents with the same fields as requested. You can try to comment/uncomment the cases just to have another confirmation.
5. For debug purposes, I finally list the documents in the collection to check whether the second document has been added or not.

I hope that this demo has clarified a few your doubts. Let me know & thanks!